# convert static_cast<char *>malloc/free to new/delete

Tags: c++, malloc, static-cast

Because segmentation fault related to malloc/free happens, I would like to convert malloc/free to new/delete.
Error occurred when malloc/free is converted to below.
Let me know how to solve it.

(original)

```
char *only_valid_data = static_cast<char*> (malloc (data_size));
```

(converted)

```
char *only_valid_data = new static_cast<char*> [data_size];
```

Comment: Whatever problem you have causing the segfault with malloc/free will almost certainly cause the same problem with new/delete.

Comment: You probably shouldn't try to write C++ by guessing at syntax.

Comment: As you say, the problem causes the same problem with new/delete though solving the compiled error. Let me know how to solve it. The results by gdb is shown in http://ait-survey.com/?page_id=7044.

Comment: @JonathanWakely you should omit *probably* from that line....

Comment: If you need a number of `char`s, other options are `std::vector<char>` and `std::string` - both of which are known not to cause segmentation faults when used properly.

Answer (score 6):

Just do

```
char* only_valid_data = new char[data_size];
```

to allocate.

To free you do

```
delete[] only_valid_data;
```

---

Important note: When you allocate memory with `new` it will allocate `data_size` ***elements***, not `data_size` bytes (like `malloc` does). The size of an element is the size of the non-pointer base type, in your case e.g. `sizeof(*only_valid_data)`. In this case the element size and the byte size is the same (as `sizeof(char)` is specified to always be `1`), but if the base type is something else it will make a big difference.

For example, if you do

```
int* int_ptr = new int[10];
```

then ten integers will be allocated, not ten bytes. This is equivalent to

```
int* int_ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(malloc(10 * sizeof(*int_ptr)));
```

Also note that for complex types, like structures and classes, allocating with `new` (or `new[]`) does more than just allocating memory, it will also make sure that the allocated object(s) constructor is called. The `malloc` function only allocates memory, it doesn't call the constructor.

---

Final note: The problem you have with the segmentation fault is probably not caused by your allocation, no matter how you allocate the memory. The problem is more likely because of something else, something you do not show in your question, like writing out of bounds of the allocated memory or dereferencing a null-pointer.

You need run your program in a debugger to catch the crash in action, it will allow you to examine the function call stack, and if the crash doesn't happen in your code then you walk up the call stack until you reach your code. There you can examine the values of variables, to help you understand why the problem occurred.

Comment: The program(pcd_io.cpp) is shown in
http://pastebin.com/J7RSu0hR
.

By gdb dubbugin, variable "only_valid_data" is assumed to be wrong.

The value of "only_valid_data"in line 1581 of the program(pcd_io.cpp)  is shown below.
(gdb) p /d only_valid_data
$1 = <optimized out>

The value of "only_valid_data"in line 1721 of the program(pcd_io.cpp)  is shown below.
(gdb) p /d only_valid_data
$2 = 46915340455952


These value is different. Is this the reason of segmentation fault?

Comment: @LenItsuki It's possible. Do you reassign `only_valid_data` somewhere between allocation and use?

Comment: Moreover, value of variable "data_size" in "char *only_valid_data = new char [data_size];" related to error was input as 11348464912.

Comment: @LenItsuki That is a very large value, and the allocation probably fails which in the case of `malloc` will mean that if it fails it would return `NULL` and if you don't check for that you will sooner or later try to dereference this null-pointer and have undefined behavior and a crash. In the case of `new` then it would raise an exception and unless you catch it the program will terminate there.

Comment: The capacity of file loaded in this program is 2.7GB. I think that a solution is to separate the loaded file.Could you have any ideas to solve it?

Comment: @LenItsuki Do you need all the data at once, or can you read smaller blocks at a time and operate on them?

Answer (score 3):

The `malloc` family (`malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`, `free`) is used almost always in C code, as C++ provides the `new` and `delete` operators which are a lot more reliable to use.

A problem with `malloc` for allocation is that you must specify the size of the type in bytes that you want to allocate. For example:

```
int* ptr = malloc(5);
```

Will not allocate space for 5 integers in memory; it will allocate 5 bytes of memory (the size of an integer is 4 bytes, so this would obviously cause problems when assigning).

To do it properly, it must be written as

```
int* ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

So that 20 bytes are allocated.

However, there are some exceptions to the case. `char`, for example only requires one byte of memory, so doing

```
char* ptr = malloc(5);
```

Will allocate enough memory to hold 5 characters, and in a way is more valid that writing:

```
char* ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(char)); //5 * sizeof(char) == 5 * 1 == 5
```

However, the `free` function does not need to know the size of the pointer to be deallocated; a `void*` is only needed.

---

Note that in C++, the return of `malloc` must be cast properly to the type wanted; `malloc` returns a `void*` type, but C++ does not allow any pointer to assign a `void*` to any pointer type like C does:

```
int* ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int)); //valid C code, invalid C++

int* ptr2 = (int*)malloc(5 * sizeof(int)); //valid C code, valid C++
```

---

In C++, the `new[]` operator resolves the issue of remembering to add the `sizeof` operator.

```
int* ptr = new int[5];//allocates 5 integers

int* ptr2 = new int(5);//be careful: this allocates a single integer with value of 5
```

Note that if the `new[]` operator has been used, the `delete[]` operator must be used. Otherwise the `delete` operator must be used:

```
int* ptr = new int[5];//allocates 5 integers
delete[] ptr;//deallocate the 5 integers

int* ptr2 = new int(5);//be careful: this allocates a single integer with value of 5
delete ptr;//deallocate the integer
```

---

The problem with your code is that it does not fit the syntax of the `new[]` operator

The syntax could be described as:

```
T* p = new T[size];
```

Thus your code:

```
char *only_valid_data = new static_cast<char*> [data_size];
```

Should be corrected to:

```
char *only_valid_data = new char[data_size];
```

As `static_cast<char*>` is not a type.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Nice answer, which certainly cost you a lot of time, but I think you have gone a little astray. You have provided a lot of side information at the top, and answered the question at the bottom. I would do the opposite. Then, you said nothing about the OP's attempt to solve a segmentation fault by switching from `malloc` to `new`, which in my opinion deserves a comment. I think Joachim Pileborg's answer is really spot-on. If you accept a small piece of advice, I would try to follow his example for future answers. More focused on the question than on writing a general guide on the topic.

Comment: The same error have been occurred yet though it changed as you indicated.

Comment: Anyway, it would be a shame if so much effort went unrecognized, so you have my +1. It's also a sort of welcome to SO. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @FabioTurati - ok, thank you for the +1. I will keep your advice in mind for my next answer, thank you:)

Comment: "*the size of an integer is 4*" might be the case on your system, but it's not a universal truth.  It can be anything from 1 (on systems where `CHAR_BIT` is at least 16) upwards.